# Quickly reshape multi-indexed covariance to 2D covariance (maintaining C order)

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

### Problem

I have an array `S` of shape `(a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d)` which represents a covariance matrix for data of shape `(a,b,c,d)`. 
I must convert `S` to shape `(a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d)` where the index transformation is C-order, i.e. the equivalent code is,

```
S_out = np.zeros([a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d],dtype=float)
for h1 in range(a*b*c*d):
    i1,j1,k1,l1 = np.unravel_index(h1, (a,b,c,d))
    for h2 in range(h1,a*b*c*d):
        i2,j2,k2,l2 = np.unravel_index(h2, (a,b,c,d))
        S_out[h1,h2] = S[i1,j1,k1,l1,i2,j2,k2,l2]
        S_out[h2,h1] = S_out[h1,h2]
```

The transpose symmetry is because it's a covariance matrix.

To build a test `S` you can use:

```
S_ = np.random.uniform(size=[a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d])
S_ = S_.dot(S_.T)#to symmetrise
S_test = np.zeros([a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d], dtype=float)
for h1 in range(a*b*c*d):
    i1,j1,k1,l1 = np.unravel_index(h1, (a,b,c,d))
    for h2 in range(a*b*c*d):
        i2,j2,k2,l2 = np.unravel_index(h2, (a,b,c,d))
        S_test[i1,j1,k1,l1,i2,j2,k2,l2] = S_[h1,h2]
```

### Question

Is there a fast way to reorder `S` so that it ends up like above?

Comment: Should `S_out` be shape (a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d)? Seems like there is an error in the current snippet.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second for loop, you start at h1 instead of 0. This leads to S_out not being equal to S. I changed it to start at 0, and then S_out and S are equal if I flatten both arrays. If this is what you mean, you can simply reshape S as shown in the last two lines of the code snippet.

```
import numpy as np

a, b, c, d = 2, 3, 4, 5
S = np.random.random([a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d])
S_out = np.zeros([a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d], dtype=float)
for h1 in range(a*b*c*d):
    i1,j1,k1,l1 = np.unravel_index(h1, (a,b,c,d))
    for h2 in range(a*b*c*d):
        i2,j2,k2,l2 = np.unravel_index(h2, (a,b,c,d))
        S_out[h1,h2] = S[i1,j1,k1,l1,i2,j2,k2,l2]
        S_out[h2,h1] = S_out[h2,h1]


# Seems like the order is not changing? Is this intended?
print('Flatted is same as input: ', (S.flatten() == S_out.flatten()).all())

# If so, we can just reshape
S_out2 = S.reshape(a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d)
print('Reshape gives same result: ', (S_out == S_out2).all())
```

Output:

```
Flatted is same as input:  True
Reshape gives same result:  True
```

Comment: The second loop starts at `h1` because `S_out` is symmetric in swapping indices. For random `S` I would expect `S.flatten() != S_out.flatten()`. Otherwise such an assertion trivially implies that a reshape will work. I'll add a snippet to build appropriate test `S`.

Comment: Note I checked and (S_test.flatten() == S_.flatten()).all() and (S_test.reshape([a*b*c*d,a*b*c*d]) == S_).all() are both True which means a simple reshape will do. Please just change your answer to use proper test case and h2 starting at h1 and I'll accept :)

Comment: I think I am missing something based on your question/follow-up here. If I add `h1` as the starting index to the second loop, then roughly half of `S_out` is still zero and not equal to `S` after the nested loop. `np.where(S_out == 0)[0].shape[0]` returns 7140 zero entries.

Comment: Ah yes, there is a typo. `S_out[h2,h1] = S_out[h2,h1]` should be `S_out[h2,h1] = S_out[h1,h2]`.